# How does one "convey" a news article in a movie?

Tags: video, audio

Here, I'm talking about a "news article" regarding the events of the movie, and not about a generic article such as "Japan Bombs Pearl Harbor" or "U.S. Invades Iraq."

> 1. Since this is an "inverview," one way is to have the reporter and source orally read their respective lines.
> 2. Since they are discussing the hero and heroine, another way is to have one "read" the article to the other.
> 3. In theory, the article could be posted on the screen so the audience can read it, but that seems like the worst alternative. Unless it was combined with either 1) or 2).

Which of these, or other methods are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the interview to be conveyed verbatim, you can have two characters discussing (or arguing about) points from the article.

The people discussing the article could even be the hero and heroine, without having them read it aloud verbatim. "Did you really say that?" "I think the author took that out of context.  What I meant was ______."

Comment: Not a bad answer. But the "source" is the heroine's boss. So I want the audience to know what the boss thinks.

Comment: Can the actual live interview be shown on screen, and then we see some other character get the article and react?

Comment: Not a bad idea. My idea was to have the reporter and source do voice-overs, while the main character pore over the paper article together.